# Adding to Cart programmatically is adding to the wrong Store?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, addtocart

I'm trying to add to cart programmatically from store 2, but it's adding products to store 1. How can I force it to add to the correct store?

This is the code I've got in my CMS page.

```
include_once "app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

$product_id = '1658';
$qty = '1';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Art Hanging System added to cart successfully. Enjoy!');
```

I've tried using `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(2)`, but this ends up adding the success message to the 1st store still and not adding the product to either site's cart.

I've tried every way I can find or think of, but as soon as I try to specify the 2nd store, then nothing happens.

How can I specify which site's cart I'm trying to work with?

Comment: In your script, `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()` creates a new quote with the current store scope. Try setting the `store_id` on the quote directly by doing `$cart->setStoreId(2)` before saving it.

Comment: Please accept your answer if that's the solution to mark this question as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this must have been an issue with how I was initiating my custom PHP page.

I found a way to make this work by creating a CMS page with a call to a template:

```
<p>{{block type="core/template" template="hanging/click-rail-configurator.phtml"}}</p>
```

Where my template file, `'hanging/click-rail-configurator.phtml'` is pointing to the file in my template path, which for me is `/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/hanging/click-rail-configurator.phtml`.

Then, in my template file, I am using the following code:

```
<?php 
try {
    $product_ids  = $_REQUEST['productsArray'];
    $qty = array('1','2','3');
    $n = 0;

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    foreach($product_ids as $product_id) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $cart->addProduct($product, $qty[$n]);
        $n++;
    }
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Art Hanging System added to cart successfully. Enjoy!');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e);
}
?>
```

`$products_ids` is an array being passed in by jQuery's post function and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the store scope when declaring your `$cart` variable, as below:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setStoreId(2)->getQuote();
```

This forces Magento to load the quote object from store with ID 2 (or whatever you put between the brackets).