# Cart Issue from calling custom code

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart, querystring

I am creating an app for Magento 1.9.And during my process, i tried to add a product to the cart by the query like this `(http://localhost/zara/rest/addtocart.php?prodid=4&qty=1)`.It's added on backend side (DB) but when I try to load cart items or cart total its shows empty cart.
My Cart code is below:

```
try{
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

$paramater = array('product' => $productId,
                    'qty' => '1',
                    'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
            );       

$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($paramater);
$cart->addProduct($product, $request);
$cart->save();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
$message = $e->getMessage();
    $ret['error'] = $message ;

}
```

I also tried this code but no luck:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    $cart->save();
```

What could be the reason that its not showing on front side? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Mahmood Rehman

You can follow the existing thread which discussed about the same cart issue.

[Adding to Cart programmatically is adding to the wrong Store?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78850/adding-to-cart-programmatically-is-adding-to-the-wrong-store)

[Magento how to add product to cart programmatically based on customer id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152909/magento-how-to-add-product-to-cart-programmatically-based-on-customer-id)

Comment: Sorry, I tried with store id but the same result.and on my case, I am not doing with the customer.

Comment: You are trying to add product to Cart for Guest user.

Comment: yes for guest user.